# Logging in as root for the first time to Oracle Solaris

Tags: virtualbox, root, solaris

ALL,

I installed latest Oracle Solaris x86 inside VirtualBox. Now, I'd like to install Oracle DB Server there.

According to the install documentations from Oracle the first step is to become root. However all my attempts to do so failed.

Could someone please give a step-by-step instruction on logging as root to latest Oracle Solaris? I can successfully do sudo, but I guess this is not enough...

Oracle documentation talks about the Management Console. But trying to execute the command found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/E29492/smcover-18.html#scrolltoc), I got `Command not found`.

Trying to execute `su ~ root` and entering the password of my local user results in `Authentication failure` message.

TIA!!

Comment: Try [How to Break/Recover Solaris root Password ?](https://www.unixarena.com/2013/09/how-to-breakrecover-solaris-root.html/)

Comment: The Management Console documentation you point to is for Solaris 10 - it's not included in Solaris 11.

Answer (score -1):

The default user login and password for Oracle Solaris is jack. Become the root user. The root password is solaris.